# Trying to find max number in a textfile(vb)

Tags: vb.net

So I have the code written below:

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLine("C:\Users\conno\Desktop\Assessment\Assessment\Assessment\bin\Debug\Leaderboard.txt")

Dim qry = (From i As String In lines Select CType(i, Integer))

Dim max = qry.Max

txtMax.Text = max
```

When I run the program to find the highest number, it finds the string instead of the integer. Can anyone help me so it just finds the highest number?

Thanks, Connor!

Comment: 1) The function name is "ReadAllLines" with an "s". If you use copy-and-paste to put your code in, you'd avoid typos like that. 2) You refer to "the string" but it is not clear what you mean by that. 3) Perhaps you are getting an error message but you've forgotten to tell us what it is. 4) I tried your code with my own test data and found that the `qry` part works properly.

Comment: Make it `ReadAllLine'S'` and it should work